# Deep Linking mobile site Issue

Tags: android, deep-linking

We have integrated android deep linking in our app with standard https scheme and working awesome. now the issue is when the user opens our mobile site on chrome browser and click on the particular link it asks user to choose either app or browser.
but we want behavior like it should not show selection popup to the user and stay into a mobile site.

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: thanks Simon for the reply.. but we have already integrated app links and it's still not working.

Comment: Test it with https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are seeing is the expected behavior. The user does have the ability permanently link the URI Scheme to your app by tapping on the "always" option when this prompt appears.

This behavior can be avoided by using App Links in addition to URI Schemes and setting autoverify to "true" in the App Links intent-filter within the Android Manifest.xml file.

For details on App Links see:  https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html and https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links/.